# tableView doesn't show anything

Tags: objective-c, tableview

I'm sure my code is withour mistake, because I have two same tableViews and both with same code, same content and same design. But I don't understand why one of my tableViews is shown, and the other one isn't. I'm using Dynamic Prototype Content, Grouped Style and both tableViews are in container view in other ViewController. Here is code:

table.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface table : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

{
    NSArray *tabledata;
    NSIndexPath* checkedIndexPath;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *tabledata;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int number;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath* checkedIndexPath;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
+(table*)instance;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger selectedRow;

@end
```

table.m

```
#import "table.h"

@interface table ()

@end

@implementation table
@synthesize tabledata;
@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize checkedIndexPath;
@synthesize number;
+(InstrumentsI*)instance {
    static table *statInst;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        statInst = [[table alloc] init];
    });
    return statInst;
}
@synthesize selectedRow;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tabledata = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"row1", @"row2", @"row3", nil];
    self.selectedRow = 0;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - TableView Data Source methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tabledata count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifer"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"identifer"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (indexPath.row == self.selectedRow)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark TableView Delegate methods

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [table instance].selectedRow = indexPath.row;
    if (indexPath.row != self.selectedRow) {
        self.selectedRow = indexPath.row;
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setTableView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have implemented all the delegates and datasource methods.

Also confirm that you have set your file's owner or controller as delegates and datasource.

Comment: That's it!! It's allways something obvious that I forgot! Thank you.

Comment: @TomasJ : One tip :) -> always think small while coding. If your code size increases and for no result, dont panic, dont experiment and waste time, simply Delete all and re-write.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload the tableview after loading the data, like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tabledata = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"row1", @"row2", @"row3", nil];
    self.selectedRow = 0;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism. It is required to actually do this, depending on when the view is drawn, it can appear without data.